# How do I carry my Draw Something contacts from my old iPad to my new iPad?

Tags: draw-something

I have a iPad 3 on which I use the free version of Draw Something and I have received as a gift a new iPad Air. I synced the new iPad using iTunes and everything moved except for my contacts (drawing partners) on Draw Something. How do I bring the previous drawing opponents/challengers to my new iPad Air?

Comment: doesn't it use the facebook?

Answer (score 1):

Save everything to your cloud which you can find In setting then go to your new I pad and sign into cloud and wahlah all your contacts are on your new iPad.

Comment: Thanks, will do new backup.  I thought I had and as everything else had come through on every other program, didn't think it was that.  This is worth a try.